# access React state element to another element in same state

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to access one react element to another element on same state.
E.g

```
this.state={
A:1,
B:A+1
}
```

So i need to access A inside B

Comment: Can you elaborate? What are the relationships of the two components? Does one render the other? Try creating a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and we can help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need more context for that, however based on the example that provided for you, cannot do that. Maybe you can try something like this.

```
state = {
    A:1
}

componentDidMount() {
   this.setState((prevState)=>({ B:prevState.A+1}));
}

--Or--

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({B:this.state.A + 1});
}
```